# Spring MVC multiple views in multiple locations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I joining my front-end(angularJs) with my back-end(Spring) and I'm facing an issue of not found pages.

now I have folders like this :

[image]

As u can see I have my index page under views among others and I also have a lot of partials inside `/resources/app/pages/...` .

I wanted to ask what's the best way to approach this ? cause writing **multiple viewResolver** is not a good solution plus there's too many pages and moving the pages to the **views** directory also not possible cause I need to change a lot of code after that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We usually just have the non JSP resources in /webapp/static and not inside WEB-INF. If we have an angular app, we put the bootstrapping JSP page into WEB-INF/view/ but all js, css etc is loaded from static/cas/mycss.css.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek As I said moving files will break my code and most of it is not mine so I'll be down to a long road.

Comment: @JBNizet  could you give me an example cause from the documentation that you've linked I need to use multiple viewResolver but it's hard to implement that cause I have multiple subfolders that contains views

Comment: Why using of multiple `ViewResolver` is not a good solution?

Comment: Cause for every subfolder I need a view resolver and maybe it will contain 1 view and there's too much, that's why.